# Java servlet : request.getParameter() returns a parameter from the query string in a POST request

Tags: java, servlets, post, parameters

I'm currently developing a Servlet that runs under Glassfish 4.
I implemented the `doPost()` method and I need to ensure that the parameters are passed using the `POST` body, and not in the query string.

I wrote a test implementation to check it:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String name = request.getParameter("name");

    response.getOutputStream().print(name);
}
```

If I call my page with `POST` with this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/myservlet/testservlet
```

and pass `name=Nico` into the post body, the value *Nico* is returned, and it's okay.

Now if I call it this way:

```
http://localhost:8080/myservlet/testservlet?name=Robert
```

and I still pass `name=Nico` in the `POST` body, *Robert* is returned, and the *name=Nico* is ignored.

I just would like to avoid parameters to be passed in the URL.
Is there a way to explicitly retrieve parameters from the `POST` body instead of body + query string?

Comment: Why are you doing this on the receiving end? If you want to avoid parameters being passed in the URL, then by the time your `doPost` runs, it's too late.

Comment: @immibis : thanks for your comment but I'm not sure to understand. I'm pretty new in servlet development and I'm not very aware of the workflow. Do you mean I could intercept the request before to achieve this?

Comment: only one Parameter 'name' ,so you can/t

Comment: @Nico What I just said isn't a servlet-specific thing. But to use an analogy, let's say I yell at you across a crowded room "HEY NICO, MY PASSWORD IS PASSWORD42". Yelling back "I'M NOT LISTENING BECAUSE YOU JUST TOLD EVERYONE YOUR PASSWORD" isn't going to achieve anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the javadoc for the `getParameter` method:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29

Like it is stated, you are sending 2 parameters on the request with the same name, one from the query string and another on the body.

Now it is up to you to either validate that no parameter is coming from the query string or read directly values from the request body.

Comment: Hi all, and thank you for your time. Well, I expected something like php's $_POST and $_GET. Finally the getParameter() method acts more like php's $_REQUEST.

Well I'll mark @hvieira's answer as good because the link provided explains my problem (although it doesn't solve it) and the suggestion to process the raw response body fits good for the question I asked.

Anyway, thanks all for your comments! And finally you're right, there's no need to wonder where the parameter comes from... I was just focused on PHP's $_POST and $_GET arrays.

Nico

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, you can read both of them using getParameterValues, the first one is query string and the second one is post body. Now you can decide which one to use.
String[] lines = request.getParameterValues("name");

Comment: In the most common case this is true. There is also a possibility to have more than 2 Strings returned by getParameterValues(). This is the case when a form contains array-names. Lets say in a form there are 2 elements named "settings[]". By calling getParameterValues("settings[]") return then 4 elements: 2 from querystring and 2 from post data. But the query string is exposed to manipulation. So it is no guaranty how to split the returned values in get and post parts.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what request.getAttribute() returns?

Anyway you can't avoid that people will try to send you evil data, either in the url or by tinkering with the post-request.

So when you work with input from a website, always imagine a hacker sitting on the other side and sending you evil content in your parameters, like sql-injections. So you need a good validation to only let good content through to your database.

Because it's not your problem if a user enters his username as a parameter in the url. Let him have the fun, if he prefers this way over the input-field. The hackers are the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is a problem of front end code, instead of servlet. Any post request submission from UI should strip query string.